# How can I speed up updating lots of rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net

I have a table that has 1.400.000 entries. Its is a simple list of documents

Table - Document

- ID             int
- DocumentPath  nvarchar
- DocumentValid
  bit

I scan a directory and set any document found in the directory as valid.

```
    public void SetReportsToValidated(List<int> validatedReports)
    {
        SqlConnection myCon = null;

        try
        {
            myCon = new SqlConnection(_conn);
            myCon.Open();

            foreach (int id in validatedReports)
            {                    
                SqlDataAdapter myAdap = new SqlDataAdapter("update_DocumentValidated", myCon);
                myAdap.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter pId = new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
                pId.Value = id;
                myAdap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(pId); 

                myAdap.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        catch (SystemException ex)
        {
            _log.Error(ex);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (myCon != null)
            {
                myCon.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

The performance of Updates is ok, but I want more. It takes more than 1 hour to update 1000000 of the documents to valid. Is there any good way to speed up the updates? I am thinking of using some kind of batch (like table valued parameters).
Each update takes some 5-10ms when profiled on SQLServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the reports in and append them together in a DataTable (since they have the same dimensions) then use the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) object for to upload the entire thing.  Will probably work better for you.  I don't think you will have memory issues given the small number of columns and rows.

Comment: I did mot know that I can use a DataTable for BulkCopy. This worked: The insert into a temporary table is now down to 40seconds http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x.aspx

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you are calling the db for each record individually. You can use the SqlDataAdapter to do bulk updates by (in a very brief nutshell):

1) define one SqlDataAdapter
2) set the .UpdateCommand on the adapter to your update sproc
3) call the .Update method on the adapter, passing it a DataTable containing the ids of documents to be updated. This will batch up the updated rows from the DataTable in to the DB, calling the sproc for each record in a batched manner. You can control the Batch Size via the .BatchSize property.
4) So what you're doing is removing the manual, row by row looping which is inefficient for batched updates.

See examples:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308055 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/61b832/4430/ 

Alternatively, you could:
1) Use SqlBulkCopy to bulk insert all the IDs into a *new* table in the database (highly efficient)
2) Once loaded in to that staging table, run a single SQL statement to update your main table from that staging table to validate the documents.

See examples:
http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/02/sqlbulkcopy-bulk-load-to-sql-server.html 
http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2011/01/sqlbulkcopy-to-sql-server-in-parallel.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the adapter and parameter every time in the loop just create them once and assign different value to the parameter:

```
            SqlDataAdapter myAdap = new SqlDataAdapter("update_DocumentValidated", myCon);
            myAdap.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter pId = new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Int);
            myAdap.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(pId); 

            foreach (int id in validatedReports)
            {
                myAdap.SelectCommand.Parameters[0].Value = id;  
                myAdap.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

This might not result in a very dramatic improvement but is better compared to the original code. Also, as you are manually executing the SqlCommand object you do not need the adapter at all. Just use the SqlCommand directly.